# I have installed KDE plasma but Konsole is missing. How to return to CLI?

Tags: archlinux, kde-plasma

I recently installed Arch Linux in my virtual box and then installed kde plasma on it by using the following command-

pacman -S plasma

When I rebooted after enabling sddm, the desktop environment did not have Konsole,  dolphin, etc.

Is there a way to return to the CLI without resetting the VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch to `tty` via `ctrl+alt+F<1-7>`.

Normally the plasma Environment runs either on `ctrl+alt+F1` or `ctrl+alt+F7` so try `2-6!`

Comment: Ctrl+alt+F2 did the job!  Thanks a lot! You saved me!

Answer (score 2):

Once you press Ctrl+Alt+F2 and logged in type the command below
sudo pacman -S konsole 
This will install Konsole 19.04.3-1-x86_64
Then you wont have to always use the Ctrl+Alt+F2 method. Also Ctrl+Alt+F1 will take you back to your GUI.

Hope this helps